# How to make Black and Isort work with Auto Save on VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autosave, python-black, isort

To make [Black](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter) and [Isort](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.isort) below work, I need to save manually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

```json
// "settings.json"

{
    ...
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter", // For Black
        "editor.formatOnSave": true // For Black
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true // For Isort
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I enabled **Auto Save** as shown below, then **Auto Save** itself works but **Auto Save** doesn't work with **Black** and **Isort** so I still need to save manually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to make **Black** and **Isort** work:

```json
// "settings.json"

{
    ...
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter", // For Black
        "editor.formatOnSave": true // For Black
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": true // For Isort
        }
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay", // For Auto Save
}
```

[image]

So, how can I make **Black** and **Isort** work with **Auto Save** on VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue myself. I solved it by using `"always"` instead of `true` for the `source.organizeImports` option.

```
// "settings.json"

{
    ...
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter", // For Black
        "editor.formatOnSave": true, // For Black
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.organizeImports": "always" // For Isort
        }
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay", // For Auto Save
}
```